# How can I use a string to call a method in Node JS

Tags: node.js

I have a function that returns a string of a method I want to call.

For example:

I call the function and it returns the string "price". I then want to use the word price to call another method ( contractObject.price() )

Is there any way to accomplish this in Node JS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use square brackets:

```
let methodName = "price";

contractObject[methodName]();
```

`contractObject["price"]` is equivalent to `contractObject.price`.

Answer (score 2):

This will work.

```
const functionToCall = yourFunction(); // this returns "price"
// call the price function like this
contractObject[functionToCall]();
```

Answer (score -3):

Ended up figuring out the answer. If I make the whole function a string and then use eval(  ) it calls the method I wanted

Comment: Don't do this, `eval()` is incredibly dangerous.

Comment: That's almost always not the right choice. See the other answers, you can just index the object with the property that you got and call the result.